# Add matrixes python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

```
A = [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
B = [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]]
sum = []

m=len(A[0])
n=len(A)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        sum.append(A[i][j]+B[i][j])

print(sum)
```

I have result `[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]`, but I need `[[2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2]]`.

Comment: You shouldn't name your variables ,,sum'', sum is python function and if you override it you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `numpy`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.add(A, B)
array([[2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

If you don't want to use `numpy`, consider the following:

```
>>> [[sum(pair) for pair in zip(sub1, sub2)] for sub1, sub2 in zip(A, B)]
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Also do **not** use `sum = []`, you will reassign the built in `sum` function, leading to `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` errors.

Comment: I can't use numpy.

Comment: @polko does the non-numpy solution work for you, then?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easier but about your current code,change it like this:

```
for i in range(n):
    v=[]
    for j in range(m):
        v.append(A[i][j]+B[i][j])
    sum.append(v)
```

Comment: Would you like to explain me it?

Comment: Yes. in each iteration you calculate a `2` and append it to `sum`. but in my solution, you create a list of `2`s, then append that list to `sum`. and in next iteration of the outer loop, you create an empty list again.@polko